# Problem on go back to previous page on browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I'm trying to understand why my browser extension is not working.
It's a simple button, that go back to the previous page.

```js
// Get the button element by its id
let backButton = document.getElementById("back-button");

// Add a click event listener to the button
backButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Use the tabs.goBack() method from the WebExtensions API to go back a page in the current tab
    browser.tabs.goBack();
});
```

```html
    <button id="back-button">Go Back</button>
```

edge browser catch these errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

both errors are on js

I'm just trying to go to the previous page, using a button on a popup

Comment: The first error occurs because `backButton` is null. Try putting the code inside a event listener for the "load" event for `window`. The second error occurs because `browser` is no defined outside of extension methods. If you want to go back in a normal document, just use `history.back()`.